# SQL select statements from multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I want to get all rows from absence table if isHealty in absence is 'Y' and isHealty from absence_history is 'N' or if row not exists in absence_history. I want to also check if eight date has passed from start_date in absence table and isHealty from absence_history is 'N' or if row not exists in absence history. Want to also check absences with user type 'A'.

PS.  I want to still get absences even if the table absence_history is empty. In my case empty table in absence_history is the same as isHealty = 'N' in absence table. The absence_history table in my app is only updated with new rows through a nightly job(quartz) and there is some cases we want to get absences before the job is running, therfore the table will be empty at first.

Currently the structure looks like:

```
User table
id  name   type
1   Jason  K
2   Adam   A
3   Marcus A

Absence table
id  user_id   isHealty healty_date start_date     type  
1    1        'Y'      2020-03-22  2020-03-03     Fever
2    2        'Y'      2020-03-05  2020-03-04     Sore throat
3    2        'N'      null        2020-03-03     Fever
4    3        'Y'      2020-03-05  2020-03-03     Sore throat
5    3        'Y'      2020-03-10  2020-03-07     Sore throat

Absence_history table
id  absence_id  isHealthy  date
1    1           'N'       2020-03-03
2    1           'Y'       2020-03-22
3    2           'Y'       2020-03-05
4    3           'N'       2020-03-03
5    4           'Y'       2020-03-06
```

The result I expect:

```
id  user_id   isHealty healty_date start_date     type  
3    2        'N'      null        2020-03-03     Fever
5    3        'Y'      2020-03-10  2020-03-07     Sore throat
```

Comment: unclear how the 3rd table comes into play. Do you first want to see if they were absent using healthy table? THen see if they are type A? Then import why they are absent. The ids on final table are from which table? Looks like the absense table.... question is pretty unclear

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, postresql...?

Comment: Your result do not match up with what your data is and what you say you want. You results with the given scenario and data would also include Absence IDs 2 and 4. It seems like what you want given your results is the Absence for Users of type K that is **only** related to isHealthy of 'N'.

Comment: And what have you tried so far???  I don't see a query that show you've tried something.

Comment: This is the query so far:  select a.id, a.user_id, a.type, a.isHealthy, a.healthy_date, a.start_date
from Absence a
inner join [User] u on a.user_id = u.id
where u.type = 'A' and a.isHealthy ='Y'
  and not exists 
  (
    select * 
    from absence_history h
    where h.absence_id = a.id
      and h.isHealthy = 'Y'
  ).

Comment: It is not clear to me which aspects of your criteria should be connected with ANDs or ORs. Trying writing it out in pseudo code with one condition per line. This [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3b0183cb740477b4fe71911e1c505a9a) has your table structure and data as most recently defined, but I know my final query is not right because I cannot figure out what your description into code.

Comment: I want to aslo get all absences if  start_date from absence table is older or equal to 8 day compared to current day. But it doesnt seems to work:                                                        I want something like this:                                                               select a.id, a.user_id, a.type, a.isHealthy, a.healthy_date, a.start_date from Absence a inner join [User] u on a.user_id = u.id where u.type = 'A' and a.isHealthy ='Y' or a.startdate<='8day' and not exists ( select * from absence_history h where h.absence_id = a.id and h.isHealthy = 'Y' )

Comment: So lets say I have an absence with startdate 2020-04-14 then I dont want to get them, because it isnt older than 8 day

Comment: This is what i want to do:

Answer (score 0):

You can `join`:

```
select a.*
from absences a
inner join users u on u.id = a.user_id
inner join healthy h on h.absence_id = a.id
where u.type = 'A' and h.is_healthy = 'Y'
```

It is quite unclear what the cardinality is between tables `absences` and `healthy`, so `exists` might come handy too:

```
select a.*
from absences a
inner join users u on u.id = a.user_id
where 
    u.type = 'A' 
    and exists (select 1 from healthy h where h.absence_id = a.id and h.is_healthy = 'Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want data that corresponds to isHealthy = 'N' or where there is not match in the Healthy table then you need to do a left join. The purpose of the **coalesce()** function is that if isHealthy is null (no match) it will equate to 'N' and thus return that row from the Absence/[User] join.

```
-- this is what your description is asking for
select a.id, a.user_id, a.type
from Absence a
inner join [User] u on a.user_id = u.id
left join Healthy h on a.id = h.absence_id
where u.type = 'A'
  and coalesce(h.isHealthy, 'N') = 'N'
```

After reviewing you question and desired results more carefully what I think you really want is Absence records where a corresponding isHealthy = 'Y' record does not exist.

```
-- this is what your results seems to be asking for
select a.id, a.user_id, a.type
from Absence a
inner join [User] u on a.user_id = u.id
where u.type = 'A'
  and not exists 
  (
    select * 
    from Healthy h
    where h.absence_id = a.id
      and h.isHealthy = 'Y'
  )
```

Here is the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f71ab959a68d7b1c912f21c11c94f12c) of my code.

Comment: But I expected only one row:   -->   3    2       Fever       .                                                                                                                          According to your demo also healthy absence is included in the result, they have become healthy after 1 day

Comment: I have changed the table structure a bit. Plz read my latest post. Do you know how this select statement looks like in that case?